# make a float:left div sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a simple solution for an easy problem, and I believe it has been applied somewhere, but not able to find the solution.

So now I'm having a very long introduction page like one of wikipedia, and a list of navigation links like wikipedia. In wikipedia, they have links back to the top at the end of every paragraph, but I don't want to do that. Instead, I'm trying to make the table sticky when scrolling down.

The current code is like this:

```
    <div id="introtable">
    <table class="normalfont">
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
                <p align="center" style="margin-top:13px;">Contents</p>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#something">something</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td style="width:25px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<p align="justify" id="something" style="margin-top:5px;">
                some texts
            </p>

            <p align="justify" style="margin-top:5px">
                some texts
            </p>

            <p align="justify" style="margin-top:5px">
                some texts
            </p>

<p align="justify" id="something" style="margin-top:5px;">
                some texts
            </p>

            <p align="justify" style="margin-top:5px">
                some texts
            </p>

            <p align="justify" style="margin-top:5px">
                some texts
            </p>
```

And the CSS is like this:

```
#introtable{
    width:255px; 
    margin-top:10px; 
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

.normalfont{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Now, the paragraph texts wrap around the table, leaving some blank space between the table and texts.

I would like the table to stick on the page while still floating left, that is, still having the paragraphs wrapping around it.

I tried adding position:fixed, but it overrides float:left, making the paragraph appearing under the table.

Is it possible via pure CSS? If not, javascript is also acceptable.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should throw together a live example because I don't really understand what the problem is

Comment: If you want the paragraph to wrap around the menu, but the menu position changes, do you want the text on the page to morph and wrap around the menu as you scroll? That will be a weird experience. If not, you can use `position: fixed` on the menu and give the menu a width, and make the `margin-left` of your paragraph section whatever the width of the menu is (so the paragraphs don't fall behind the menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done with pure CSS, but regrettably I'm not a CSS expert. But using JS (with JQuery in this example), you could alter the tables `margin-top` on scrolling. The wrapped text above will still be wrapped but this won't be visible and the text will not need to move around as much.

Since setting the css on scrolling can give a kind of jerky effect (especially if handled async), I've adapted the setting of the margin-top to a short animation to have the table ease into place:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    $('#introtable').stop().animate({'margin-top': 10 + $(this).scrollTop()}, 10);
});
```

Example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1bvj7nk/)

Comment: This is the appearance I'm trying to achieve, and it's simple enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `position` to `fixed` (`position: fixed`) of the container that you want to remain on the same place on the browser. Then you can position it exactly, by saying: `bottom: 30px; right: 0` etc.

Comment: As I mentioned, when I tried position:fixed, the paragraph appeared under the navigation table, which is not what I want. I would like to stick the table position while keeping texts wrap around it.

Comment: @WangTianjian Okay. Maybe you could try this: set the container width to be 15% while floated, and the content to be with width of 70%. I have faced the same problem once, and this settled it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to have a side bar that sticks to the screen and allows you to scroll the page, I think you need to reassess the layout of html you have.

In your currently layout you are asking the copy to float around the side bar section no matter where it is. It would be healthier for your code to to frame them out differently.

My recommendation is you use a framework such as: bootstrap, foundation, materialize.

Or

Use Flexbox [- example - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp)

Also, it's not the best practice to just have p tags floating around all willy nilly.

---

If you just want your box to stick to the corner

```
class {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
  left:20px;
}
```

Comment: How is this a poor answer, the code is written incorrectly for achieving the desired outcome

Comment: Sorry I'll be more clear in the future, thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you... 

Did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you should give your paragraphs some `margin-left` to avoid overlapping:

```
#introtable{
position:fixed;
width:255px; 
margin-top:10px; 
margin-bottom:10px;
float:left;
}
p{
margin-left:15%;
}
```